# Is pm.max_children in php-fpm equal to the maximum number of parallel downloads?

Tags: php, linux, web, nginx

I'm preparing a web server (gentoo linux, nginx, php-fpm, php) for my website. During configuration I came to pm.max_children value in fpm config. The default is 50. If I plan to serve some big files with php, would each client block whole thread during the download? What will happen to 51st client trying to open the website / start download?

According to what I've read - one child = one thread. If I run my server on let's say quad core newest series xeon cpu with 32GB ddr3 - how many clients or threads could the cpu / system survive?

Is there any limit in linux of maximum open sockets / threads / processes?
Os is gentoo amd64 (fresh installation), nginx 1.4.0, php-5.4

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stream your files via php, then yes, each download will be a php process. This is also why it's a bad idea to do so. Php should be used to process data into a comprehensible webpage. Serving files is for a webserver. Perhaps you can rewrite your application to generate unique files and then redirect to that location and have the webserver handle it.
The number of open sockets is configured via `limits` on a per process basis. Sockets count towards the number of open files.

Comment: Hi @Melvyn, I am also serving downloadable files. How can I redirect files to be serve by webserver? I'm using nginx.

Comment: You copy the file from a location not served from the webserver to a unique (randomly generated) name into a directory that /is/ served by the webserver. Our you generate the file on the fly. You then send a 302 header with location pointing to your file.

Comment: I'm using drupal. Can you give me some little guidance? Is there any tutorial for this?